# Exactly Calculate Dealer Hand in Blackjack

Tags: python, recursion, probability, blackjack

I am writing a program that exactly derives basic strategy. To do this it calculates the odds that the dealer gets a 17/18/19/20/21/Bust. My code to get the dealer odds is below, but I can't figure out how to recursively call it so that it generates odds for ANY possible cards dealt to it, instead of just the first card dealt to it.

```
Odds = [0] * 33
Odds[dealerTotal] = 100
    

def getDealerOdds(dealerTotal):
branchScenario = []

# missing indent
if dealerTotal < 17:
    for card in values:
        branchScenario.append(dealerTotal + int(card))

    redistribute = Odds[dealerTotal]
    Odds.pop(dealerTotal)
    for num in branchScenario:
        if num != dealerTotal + 10:
            Odds[num] += redistribute / 13
        else:
            Odds[num] += (redistribute * 4) / 13

        # recursion here(obviously doesn't currently  work): 
        if num < 17:
            getDealerOdds(num)

        

return Odds
```

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation so it runs, and provide an example of how you would call it. Explain what outcome you'd expect and what you're getting instead. Also, what's `values`?

Comment: You're using values in `branchScenario` both as an in index (e.g. in `Odds[num]`) and as a value (e.g. in `num < 17`). And you make a similar mistake when you `Odds.pop(dealerTotal)`, which would remove the element at that index (and return it). Your code seems to make very little sense as a whole, so you might want to focus on a specific part you're having trouble with and asking about that, because it's currently not even entirely clear what the code *should* be doing.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate dealer odd, you need to enumerate all possible arrangement that can happent during a game;
You should make 2 different files (1 file for burn arrangement and 1 other for score arrangement)

For example you can have bj_score.txt like this :

DEALER CARD ACE

1 1 1 3 6 7 19 8

DEALER CARD 2

1 2 3 6 9 21 6

For the first one, you have "1 1 1 3 6 7" arrangement give to the dealer a score of 19 and can happent in 8 different combination;

I have generated on my own more than 4600 different arrangements just for the score;

You cannot get exact odd of the dealer if you don't enumerates all possible arrangements;